# Integrate ckeditor in asp.net core mvc

Tags: ckeditor, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to integrate an web based html editor in asp.net core project. I downloaded CKEditor and placed the unzipped folder in `wwwroot` folder.

I have referenced "ckeditor.js" in `_Layout.cshtml` using following script tag.

```
<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Then, I've used following code to display the editor.

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');</script>
```

On using these lines of code in the empty About.cshtml of Home Folder, the editor was displayed. But the editor was not displayed when using the same code in another `.cshtml` file. The Code is given below

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading border">
        Create User
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row no-margin">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form asp-action="Edit" class="form-horizontal bordered-group" role="form">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="_id" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Subject" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="MailFrom" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input asp-for="MailFrom" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="MailFrom" class="text-danger" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Body" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">

                            @* CKEDitor  *@
                            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">
                            </textarea>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');</script>
```

Why is the editor not displayed in another `cshtml` file?

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML in the browser source, if the script tag for ckeditor.js is actually included ? Does the browser javascript console show any error ?

Comment: Thanks, I found the error "CKEditor not redered in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've also faced the same problem while integrating CKEditor in aps.net mvc project. After trying to determine the error I found that the Layout of the page is different. You may have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Use id attribute and use a hash on the name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('#editor1');</script>
```